# How to represent spatial data in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, postgis

Can someone tell me how to represent spatial data (coming from postgis) in Cassandra?

Answer (score 2):

This presentation was pretty interesting, on the topic of spatial data in Cassandra, and may help:

http://www.readwriteweb.com/cloud/2011/02/video-simplegeo-cassandra.php

Answer (score 1):

Please provide a bit more detail on what you are trying to achieve.

This is particularly important for Cassandra (as opposed to a relational database), because you need to model the data to support the specific queries you need, rather than modelling the domain in a fairly generic way and using SQL to define queries afterwards.

Are you just trying to look up lat/longs for entities with unique identifiers, or do you have more complex shapes associated with your entities - or what?

Comment: I'm having the same question as the OP. What I want to achieve is a simple query: given a lat/long return all points that are less than x miles distant from it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Responding to Mr. Roland (and hopefully the OP):

You'd need to come up with your own indexing scheme, and store the indexes in Cassandra.

For example, you could subdivide the space into squares (perhaps using a hierarchical structure such as a quadtree) and store each square in a Cassandra row, with the columns storing the objects that fall within the square. Your client code would need to determine the correct square for each lat,long, then look up the objects in that square (or squares) that cover the radius you desire, then do a final client-side filter to remove any objects that are just outside the radius due to them being stored in squares.